# Buying MS SQL server, confused about CAL needs

Tags: sql-server, licensing

I'm extremely confused as to which version of SQL server to buy...

I've found versions for around $599 and then some for around $1,100...

Currently we're running Express and only need to upgrade because of the database limit

The setup is as follows:

- There's the SQL Server.
- There is a app running on a terminal server, which in turn makes use of the SQL server

I'm confused on the CALs... there is technically only one "user" on the SQL server (sa) and only one computer (terminal server) will be connecting to it

Comment: What version are you looking at specifically.  Different version of SQL Servers might have different rules, best way to determine your actual needs, is to contact your sales representative.

Comment: Express has been fine and like I mentioned, the only reason for purchasing is the DB size limit.

Because of this I would imagine 2012 standard would be fine (the software we use is apparently incompatible with SQL 2014)

Also, is there any place you would recommend purchasing SQL server? There are so many options (and confusing when the software company just gives you a server with express and says "here...")

Answer (score 1):

> I'm confused on the CALs... there is technically only one "user" on the SQL server (sa) and only one computer (terminal server) will be connecting to it

You cannot multiplex MS SQL like that.  If you have an application that uses SQL server, and 100 people use that program to access the data, then you need 100 SQL CALs.

More info from Microsoft on multiplexing - [Licensing brief: Multiplexing—Client Access License (CAL) requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/Licensing/learn-more/brief-multiplexing-CALs.aspx):

> This brief explains how multiplexing impacts the licensing of
>   Microsoft server operating systems and server products licensed under
>   the Microsoft server/Client Access License (CAL) model. "Multiplexing"
>   is when customers use hardware or software to pool connections,
>   reroute information, or reduce the number of devices or users that
>   directly access or use a product. Multiplexing can also include
>   reducing the number of devices or users a product directly manages.

From the SQL-specific area of the brief:

> SQL Server CALs are required for users who directly input into, query,
>   or view data from a SQL Server database. Similarly, SQL Server CALs
>   are required for users or devices that input data into, query, or view
>   data from a SQL Server database through a pooling device. ***This
>   includes users who view data through web-based applications or enter
>   information into a database through an intermediary product***. (Note:
>   Customers can also license SQL Server on a per-core basis, thus
>   negating any need for SQL Server CALs.)

Comment: Okay, are user CALs per user account (windows) or per head (some workstations are using a single user account but are shared with multiple employees)

Comment: Per-User CALs are per 'head'.  I'm pretty sure you can also get SQL per-Device CALs, which would be a CAL for a single device, regardless of who's using it.

Answer (score 0):

This link gives you a complete breakdown of the supported functions of the different SQL versions.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx

Now what edition you need depends on what functions you need. If your fine with express and just need a higher DB limit and have an app running on a terminal server then I am willing to bet Standard is where you want to go.

This link talks about CALs: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/product-licensing/client-access-license.aspx

I have never personally needed to worry about CALs but my understanding of them is you need a CAL for each user accessing the DB at one time. So if 4 people login with the sa account at the same time you need 4 CALs. There are other licensing models that make it so you don't have to worry (i.e. core licensing).